# Lower bound on the probability of a ratio of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two positive random variables defined on the same sample space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ such that $0<X\leq Y$, but they may NOT be independent. Let $0<\alpha<\beta$. Is the following inequality correct?
$$
\mathbb{P}\Bigl(\frac{X}{Y}\geq \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\Bigr)\geq \mathbb{P}(X\geq \alpha)\mathbb{P}(Y\leq\beta). 
$$
The above inequality can be easily verified provided that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But what if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $X=Y\cdot (\alpha /(2 \beta))$, the inequality cannot hold

Comment: Have you tried special cases with dependency?  Examples: X=Y or X=1-Y with both in the unit interval.

Comment: @NN2   In general $\alpha \le \beta$.  For your example, probability = 1, so inequality always holds.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks for pointing out this. I've updated my question.

Comment: @NN2  Are you sure?  I get $0$ for both sides.  Maybe my calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality holds if $\mathsf{P}(X\ge \alpha)=0$ (trivially) or $\mathsf{P}(X\ge \alpha)>0$ and $\mathsf{P}(Y\le \beta\mid X\ge \alpha)\ge\mathsf{P}(Y\le \beta)$ because in the latter case
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(X\beta\ge Y\alpha)&=\mathsf{P}(X\beta\ge Y\alpha,X\ge \alpha)+\mathsf{P}(X\beta\ge Y\alpha,X< \alpha) \\
&\ge \mathsf{P}(X\beta\ge Y\alpha,X\ge \alpha) \\
&\ge \mathsf{P}(\beta\ge Y,X\ge \alpha) \\
&=\mathsf{P}(X\ge\alpha)\mathsf{P}(Y\le \beta\mid X\ge \alpha) \\
&\ge \mathsf{P}(X\ge\alpha)\mathsf{P}(Y\le \beta).
\end{align}
For a counterexample, consider $X\sim U[0,1]$, $Y=2X$, $\alpha=0.6$, and $\beta=1$. In this case, $\mathsf{P}(X\beta\ge Y\alpha)=0$ but $\mathsf{P}(X\ge \alpha)\mathsf{P}(Y\le \beta)=0.4\times 0.5>0$.